# Spring option create-session="never" is ignored in some scenarios?

Tags: spring-security

For some web services I want to disable use of sessions. I added *create-session="never"* to the config:

```
<beans:bean id="http403EntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>
<http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint"
    create-session="never">
    <custom-filter ref="x509Filter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
</http>
```

This works for most cases, except when the pre-authenticated user has a client certificate which is not registered in the application, so our *AuthenticationUserDetailsService* throws a *UsernameNotFoundException*.
If the user has no certificate or has a registered certificate, no session is created (no Set-Cookie header in the HTTP response). In the described case a cookie is sent. It (the cookie respectively the session) is also evaluated on each following request, even if the client certificate is changed (basically allowing a session fixation attack - the app uses the saved authentication instead of re-authenticating on each call).

We use Spring security 3.0.5. Tested with Tomcat 6 and 7 and also JBoss 7.1.1.

Why is a session created in the described scenario?

PS: The session fixation problem can be probably workarounded by setting *checkForPrincipalChanges* in the *AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter*, but I am interested in the answer to why a session is created at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit was https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-1476 :

In case of unauthorized access the following method in class *AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter* would create a session and store the exception there:

```java
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Cleared security context due to exception", failed);
    }
    request.getSession().setAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION, failed);
}
```

In the fix they changed the last line, they removed the getSession() call so the AuthenticationException is stored in the request.

To fix our project I created a new class that extends *X509AuthenticationFilter* and there I overrode the method *unsuccessfulAuthentication* with same content except I also removed the *getSession()* call.